# Is there a way of labeling the number of points with the same coordinates?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling, cartography, virtual-layer

After reading through the following question (which is kinda related but not quite what I need):

[How can I show points on the same coordinate as e.g. a bigger symbol in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74019/how-can-i-show-points-on-the-same-coordinate-as-e-g-a-bigger-symbol-in-qgis)

I found out that there might be a need to label these locations that have multiple points with same lat/long values. For example, if a location has 20 features in it, I want the label to say 20. Or even more useful: if a location has 20 features in the location, and 15 fulfill a condition (string = abc), I want the label to say 15.

Is there a way of doing so in QGIS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nice question! PyQGIS to the rescue!

Follow these steps to get a new field (in your original layer) called `label` with the number of points that lie in the same location:

1. Active (select) your layer in the QGIS ToC.
2. Run this code snippet in the QGIS Python console:

   ```py
   from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

   lyr = iface.activeLayer()

   # Create New Field
   lyr.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("label", QVariant.Int)])
   lyr.updateFields()
   fIdx = lyr.fieldNameIndex( 'label' )

   # Create Spatial Index
   idx = QgsSpatialIndex()
   for f in lyr.getFeatures():
     idx.insertFeature(f)

   # Use the Spatial Index
   attrFeatMap = {}
   for f in lyr.getFeatures():
     if not f.id() in attrFeatMap:
       res = idx.intersects( f.geometry().boundingBox() )
       for id in res:
          attrFeatMap[id] = { fIdx : len(res) }

   # Write calculated count to the label field
   lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues( attrFeatMap )
   ```
3. Open layer properties and configure labels selecting the `label` field we've just populated.
4. This is the result:

   [image]

---

**EDIT:**

As you would also like to filter by an attribute, you can define an expression in the beginning of the code (for example, after the `Create New Field` block):

```
expr = QgsExpression( '"string"=\'{}\''.format("abc") )
```

and replace **the two** calls to `lyr.getFeatures()` by:

```
lyr.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
```

That way you'll only get the count of the points with the same coordinates that fulfill the `string=abc` condition.

Comment: Seems exactly what I've needed, will test tomorrow

Answer (score 10):

If I understand, you want aggregate a layer by location.
You will need SQL for that, so create a virtual layer (Qgis >= 2.14) with a query like :

```
SELECT geometry, count(*) AS count FROM your_layer GROUP BY geometry
```

You can now use the "count" field of the virtual layer as label.

For adding the filter by the text field :

```
SELECT 
  geometry, 
  count(*) AS count_total,
  count(CASE WHEN filter_field = "abc" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as count_filter
FROM your_layer GROUP BY geometry
```

Adapt words to your layer : your_layer, filter_field and "abc".

Comment: I can't click ok on that filter query. My error is Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected FUNCTION, expecting $end

Eval Error:
No root node! Parsing failed?

Comment: @Pierma, how have you managed to use a SQL statement within QGIS?

Comment: Go to `Layer --> Add Layer --> Add Virtual Layer...` It's a very recent functionality!

Comment: Yes, sorry, don't use the filter query (no support of sql functions). The query only work for a virtual layer.  Do as Germán Carrillo explain. It will create a new layer in your project. This new layer is dynamic, so if your data change, the virtral layer will update (as a virtual field).

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can use Rule-based labeling

shapefile point before the rule
[image: fig_1]

all the points they label.

[image: fig_2]

after the rule:

[image: fig_3]

using rules you can specify which labels to show, even using conditional statements

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you've done in your filtro? Also I can't seem to get it labeling the number of points

Comment: sorry, I remedied!

Comment: sorry, I misread the question.
I agree with the use of the virtual layer.

Comment: Your answer is useful but not for this very particular case. Thanks anyway